# Django queryset all fields of foreign key

Tags: django, django-views

I am looking for an elegant and efficient way to pull data out of two tables that have a one-to-one relationship.

Here are my models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.BooleanField()

class ContactDetails(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_fax = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and my view:

```
def showContact(request):
    contacts = ContactDetails.objects.select_related('name').all()
    print contacts.values() // debugging in console
    return render(request, 'contacts/listContacts.html', { 'contacts': contacts } )
```

What I try to achieve is a list in my template like:

name, contact_phone, contact_fax, country, status

This again is something that must be so super simple, but I just stuck since a while with this now.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using `.contact_name.country` and `.contact_name.status`?

Comment: That's it. As I thought, super simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields on related models can be [accessed via their given relation field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships).

```
if somedetails.contact_name.status:
  print somedetails.contact_name.country
```